# cleanup batch file

Tags: batch-file, wincvs

I'm writing a batch file to cleanup my source folders.  I want to delete all wincvs generated files with a prefix of .#

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B .#*.*') DO DEL "%%G"
```

the problem I'm having is that it's not deleting my files within subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to do

```
DIR /S /B .#*.*
```

to list out the directories recursively

Answer (score 2):

I think you need DEL **/S**

Comment: I don't think kevin is looking to delete directories recursively, but rather find the files within directories, and then delete them.

Comment: yup missing the /S in the DIR

Comment: he probably meant `DEL /S .#*.*`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
FOR /R C:\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER %%G IN (.#*.*) DO DEL %%G
```

Comment: I didn't get your solution to work, but I just noticed it's missing a leading period in .#*.*

Comment: sorry kevin, I didn't tested it before, but now it works; do you want to give a try?

Comment: yeah still no luck.  not sure what the issue is

Comment: well, that meant to run inside a batch file; if you try to run directly at command prompt, you should to remove a %;